# Complex Django queryset filtering, involving Q objects and tricky logic

Tags: python, django, performance, django-queryset, django-q

I have a web-based chat app developed in Django. People can form their own chat groups in it, invite others and chatter away in the said groups.

I want to isolate all users who were recently online AND: (i) have already been sent an invite *for a given group*, OR (ii) have already participated (i.e. **replied**) at least once *in the same given group*. Note that `user` is a vanilla `django.contrib.auth` `user`.

To accomplish this, I'm writing:

```
online_invited_replied_users = User.objects.filter(id__in=recently_online,(Q()|Q()))
```

Assume `recently_online` to be correctly formulated. What should be the two **Q objects**?

The first `Q()` ought to refer `invitees`, the second to users who have replied at least once. I seem to be running into code-writer's block in formulating a well-rounded, efficient db query here. Please advise!

---

Relevant models are:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    topic = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(200)])
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class GroupInvite(models.Model):
    #this is a group invite object
    invitee = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='invitee')
    inviter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name ='inviter')
    sent_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    which_group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

class Reply(models.Model):
    #if a user has replied in a group, count that as participation
    text = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(500)])
    which_group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    writer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

*Note: feel free to ask for more info; I'm cognizant of the fact that I may have left something out.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For users that are already invited to a group `group`, follow the `GroupInvite.invitee` foreign key backwards.

```
already_invited = Q(invitee__which_group=group)
```

The related_name you chose, `invitee`, doesn't really make sense, because it's linking to an group invite, not a user. Maybe `group_invites_received' would be be better.

For users that have already replied, follow the `Reply.writer` foreign key backwards.

```
already_replied = Q(reply__which_group=group)
```

In this case it's `reply`. because you haven't specified a related name.

Note that your current pseudo code

```
User.objects.filter(id__in=recently_online,(Q()|Q()))
```

will give an error 'non-keyword arg after keyword arg'.

You can fix this by either moving the non-keyword argument before the keyword argument,

```
User.objects.filter((Q()|Q()), id__in=recently_online)
```

or put them in separate filters:

```
User.objects.filter(id__in=recently_online).filter(Q()|Q())
```

Finally, note that you might need to use `distinct()` on your queryset, otherwise users may appear twice.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer, Alasdair. The final query I've constructed as per your advice is (yet to sanitize the related name): `User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids,(Q(invitee__which_group_id=group_id)|Q(reply__which_group_id=group_id))).distinct('user')` This gives me a `non-keyword arg after keyword arg` error, which I've never seen before. What might that be? *p.s. I changed the which_group reference to which_group_id, since I had that readily lying around*

Comment: Solved the ordering problem by referring to the documentation for complex queries with Q objects here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Glad you solved it. I've updated the answer, explaining that you must put the non keyword `Q()` argument before any keyword arguments like `id__in=recently_online`.